# Search for files without extension in Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Is it possible to search for a file just by its name without knowing its extension (jpg or png)?

All the docs use filename.extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, a "file" in Google Cloud Storage is just an object with a name that may contain things that look like a "file" or a "folder" or a "file path". This means that `foo` is just as valid as `foo.txt` is just as valid as `path/to/foo.txt` (more on object naming [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming#objectnames)). We use an extension in the docs simply because most developers are familiar with files having some extension, and we didn't want to make the path seem arbitrary or like something other than a file.

To search, GCS thus has the concept of prefix match in their `list` API ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list)), which would allow you to query for things like "give me all the files whose prefix is `path/to/foo`, which would return `foo` and `foo.txt` if both `path/to/foo` and `path/to/foo.txt` existed.

Firebase Storage chose not to expose a list API for a few reasons, but primarily because:

1. we introduced a file/folder like hierarchy, which makes this feature function differently
2. there are issues listing files when a user may not have access to all of them (do you return a partial set or nothing?)
3. we have a [Realtime Database](http://firebase.google.com/docs/database) that can be used to store lists of URLs that are easily stored and synced across devices in milliseconds.

If you're committed to doing this, you can use the GCS `list` API, or use [GCloud](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-common) on the server.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications, Mike. About the points you made on the Firebase Storage API:
1. I know the folder path, but don't know the images extensions.
2. I return product images via pagination (infinite scroll)
3. I'm using and loving it. haha